# "Я не слушаю то, что мне говорят" или "Я не слушаю того, что мне говорят"?

Tags: грамматика, местоимения

Как правильно: "Я не слушаю то, что мне говорят" или "Я не слушаю того, что мне говорят"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше выбрать Р.п.: Я не слушаю того, что мне говорят.

Обоснование для использования Р.п.:

1) Если в качестве зависимого слова используется местоимение: не допущу этого; не делайте того. [Какой падеж нужен при отрицании? | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67)

2)  При глаголах восприятия, мысли, желания, ожидания (видеть, слышать, понимать, думать, знать, хотеть, желать, ожидать и т.п.), например: Печали в ее словах Самгин не слышал (Горький); Он... деревни не знал (Чехов); Степка проглотил... конфеты и даже не заметил их вкуса (В. Гроссман); [§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в данном случае оба варинта корректны. Подробнее о том, какой падеж нужен при отрицании, см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr)?